# how to prevent text from increasing the width of a div

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend, width

If I have a div and a span with some text in it like so

```
<div>
  <span> some text </span>
</div>
```

I find that if I increase the amount of text in the span, then the width of the div ends up increasing as well to accomodate for the increased space needed; How can I make it so that the div stays the same width? I know I can set a `width` css property on it to keep it static but is there a cleaner way of doing it without using `width`?

Comment: You need to give more information. An unstyled div by default will take up all the available width so it won't usually increase or decrease in width depending on amount of text.

Answer (score -1):

A `<div>` is a block level element, so it shouldn't be changing in size. It should take up 100% of the available width. Though the `<span>` can change in size, as its an inline element.

That being said, if you've styled your `<div>` as inline, the `width` property is as "clean" as you will get. It's the quickest and shortest way to ensure an inline element won't grow or shrink.